# Rails: Posting Multiple Checkbox Values To Controller On Change Event

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, session-variables, onchange

I have a paginated table with multiple objects and want to pass their IDs to a session variable depending on if their row's checkbox tag has been selected to store as the user browses across multiple pages before exporting the final list of IDs. It is currently working when I select each row individually, but when I hit the "Select All" checkbox, only the last ID on each page ends up being saved to the session variable

In order to do so, I am passing each ID via a change event:

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $('#selectall').click(function(i, v){
$('.css-checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked).trigger("change");
    });

var checkCount = $('.css-checkbox').length;
$('.css-checkbox').click(function(i, v){
    $('#selectall').prop('checked',$('.css-checkbox:checked').length  == checkCount)
});

$('.css-checkbox').change(function(){
$.post('user_exports/update_user_export_session', { object_id:  $(this).val(), checked: this.checked});
    });
});

</script>
```

Update action in controller:

```
def update_user_export_session

  render :nothing => true

  session[:object_ids] ||= []

  if params[:checked] == "true"
      session[:object_ids] << params[:object_id]
  else
      session[:object_ids].delete(params[:object_id])
  end

end
```

When I click the SelectAll checkbox, the rails server shows 10 parameters getting passed to the update_session method in the controller, but the session[:object_ids] ends up with only one ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. On the triggering of the change event, although it was logged as occurring in separate posts to the controller, in reality it sends all change events at once and so the logic in the controller only interpreted the last `params[:checked]`. I needed to pass it in as an object and then post after all ids were collected.

```
$('#selectall').click(function(i, v){
  $('.css-checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked).trigger("change");
  $.post('user_exports/update_user_export_session', { object_ids: row_ids });
});


var row_ids = {};

$('.css-checkbox').change(function(i, v){
  row_ids[$(this).val()] = this.checked
  });
```

Controller Code:

```
 def update_user_export_session

  render :nothing => true

  session[:object_ids] ||= []

if params[:object_ids]
 params[:object_ids].each do |object_id|    

   if object_id[1] == "true"
      session[:object_ids] << object_id[0] if ! session[:object_ids].include?(object_id[0])
   else
      session[:object_ids].delete(object_id[0])
   end

  end

 end

end
```